# System View for Not Sent Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, sql, subscriber

I am looking for a system view in Marketing Cloud, which will have the list of subscribers who didn't receive emails because of any of the below reason.

> Held
>
> List Detective Exclusion
>
> Account Level Opt Out

There is a Data Extract for Not Sent, but then I will have to import it to a DE and then query for the ones which were not sent. I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this without using Data Extract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no [**data view**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/) for *Not Sent*, unfortunately. It'd be nice if such a thing existed.

What you've described with the Data Extract is the only way (as far as I know).